# WPF webrowser control - flash working only first time

Tags: wpf, flash, webbrowser-control

I have a very strange problem on my wpf application.
I use a webbrowser control to display a third-party web page that uses flash to provide some functionality.

On internet explorer 9 and 10 i have a particular behaviour : the first time I open the webbrowser control everything works fine, and the application puts a .SWF file inside my temporary internet files folder. When I close and reopen the webcontrol, the following error arise :

"object does not support property or method 'UpdateTimeLeft'".

If i manually delete the .SWF file inside the temporary folder, close ad reopen the application, everything works fine again.

This is the code that arise the exception :

```
var swfUrl = "//" + serverName + "/js/tv/FlashTurboLotto3.swf";
    var expressSwfUrl = "//" + serverName + "/js/tv/expressInstall.swf";
    var flashvars = {}; 
    var params = {wmode:"transparent", allowscriptaccess:"always" };
    var attributes = {id:"FlashTurboLotto3",  name:"FlashTurboLotto3", align:"top"};

    swfobject.embedSWF(
            swfUrl, 
            "flashcontent", 
            "100%", 
            "197", 
            "9.0.0", 
            expressSwfUrl, 
            flashvars,
            params,
            attributes
        );


    function updateTimeleft(drawID, timeleft)
    {   
        var swf = document.getElementById("FlashTurboLotto3");
        swf.updateTimeleft(parseInt(drawID), timeleft);
    }
```

does anyone have an idea of why this appens and how to solve the issue?
Thank in advance.

Comment: Forgot to give other informations : the problem appears only in webbrowser control : if I open the page normally in IE, everything works fine, with or without the .swf file inside the temporary folder.

On IE11, no .Swf file appears in temporary folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - It is a very particular bug of Flash. Sometimes happens that when the flash application runs in a non-native browser (like, in my case, a webbrowser control in WPF) the javascript fails at retrieving the .swf file from the cache, so the Flash object will not get initialized.

I solved, for now, by forcing to not use the browser cache, simply adding a random value to the .Swf download Url.